# Norm in a Vector Space

Tags: analysis

A vector space with norm $\parallel\cdot\parallel$ Satisfy for two vectors the following

$\parallel x+y\parallel=\parallel x\parallel +\parallel y\parallel$

i need to proof the fallowing statement

$\parallel \alpha x+\beta y\parallel=\alpha\parallel x\parallel +\beta\parallel y\parallel$

for all $\alpha\geq0$ and $\beta\geq0$, and also this norm it's not necessary induced by an inner product

The fact that

$\alpha\parallel x\parallel +\beta\parallel y\parallel\geq\parallel \alpha x + \beta y\parallel$

it's clear because the property of the norm, what i can't proof it's the fact that

$\alpha\parallel x\parallel +\beta\parallel y\parallel\leq\parallel \alpha x + \beta y\parallel$

i will appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: Use the definition of the norm $||x|| = \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$ to verify your inequality.

Comment: @VictoriaM I forgot to say that the norm it's not necessary induced by an inner product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed $\alpha, \beta$ to $a,b$. Assume without loss of generality that $b\leq a$. Then $\left\Vert ax+by\right\Vert =\left\Vert
a(x+y)+(b-a)y\right\Vert \geq a\left\Vert x+y\right\Vert -(a-b)\left\Vert
y\right\Vert =a(\left\Vert x\right\Vert +\left\Vert y\right\Vert
)-(a-b)\left\Vert y\right\Vert $

$=a\left\Vert x\right\Vert +b\left\Vert y\right\Vert $ and $\left\Vert
ax+by\right\Vert \leq a\left\Vert x\right\Vert +b\left\Vert y\right\Vert $.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, now i see it clear thank's :)

Answer (score 0):

To show that the norm is induced by an inner product you can show that the norm satisfies the parallelogram law and then use the polarization identity to recover the norm.